# Getting 400 response from the OAUth API through Jersey Java code But working fine (200) through REST Client

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, jersey

```
While working on a Micro-Service, I have to hit the REST OAuth api of the 3rd party. I am using the Spring Boot Application with Jersey library. Now the problem is that I am getting 400 response every-time from my java code.

If I hit the same call using the REST client, I get the 200 response code and desired response as well. Why so ?
```

Below is the Java source code for the same -

```
@Produces("application/json")
@POST
@Path("/endPoint")
@Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
public JSONObject getAccessToken(@FormParam("item1") String item1,@FormParam("item2") String item2,@FormParam("item3") String item3,@FormParam("item4") String item4) throws Exception {
  System.out.println("Enter to test");
    String extendedUrl = "?item1="+item1+"&item2="+item2+"&item3="+item3+"&item4="+item4;

JSONObject jObject = null;
try {
  jObject = postCall(extendedUrl);
}
catch (Exception e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println("Box Auth Response :: "+jObject.toJSONString());

return jObject;
```

}

// Short description of the logic to execute the request

```
public void postCall(String extendedUrl)
{ 
String url = "baseurl";
url+=extendedUrl;
HttpsURLConnection conn = openConnection(apiUrl);
conn.connect();
status = conn.getResponseCode();
String responseContentType = conn.getContentType();
System.out.println("responseContentType ::"+responseContentType);
}
```

Am I missing something in my code? Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try adding `content type` as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`? Also post the exact request that is being hit when you run it via code. Some debug log?

Comment: Yes I did. I can't post the exact request because of the  security issue.

Comment: Logs -
Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://base_url/token?code=yMZYK2MM7t87uApLsfzFtJ5IOHVZ8NSz&client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&grant_type=authorization_code
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)